# convert a string collection into a string array in powershell

Tags: powershell

as the title says how can I convert a string collection into a string array in powershell don't know where to start with this as I am new to powershell. Would it be anything like `String[])$viewFields.toArray(new String[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try type conversion (`[object[]]`). Here is an example:

```
$x = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList # Definitely not an object array
([object[]]$x).GetType() # Object[]
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an array out of anything surround with `@(...)`. To create an array of a specific type, `System.Array` has some [factory methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/zb3cfh7k) and use `[type]` to get a `Type` object. Thus

```
$theArray = @($viewFields.toArray([array]::CreateInstance([string], 0)))
```

Comment: `new String[0]`? What is it? I cannot recognize this as a valid PowerShell syntax.

Comment: @ForNeVeR Ooops, too much copy and paste :-)